# Converting OnClick Javascript to Lightning Component

Tags: apex, javascript, lightning

For the last month or so, I have been trying to come up with a way to convert a Javascript button to a Lightning component/action without much success.

Currently the button we have uses the following code:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/10.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/10.0/apex.js")} 
var result = sforce.apex.execute("orderOutput","generate", {genericId:"{!Opportunity.Id}"}); 
window.alert(result ); 
window.location.reload(true);
```

This button uses a piece of Apex code in the background that basically allows us to generate a text EDI order that another system picks up and manipulates.

The code in the background looks like this:

```
global class orderOutput {

    webservice static String generate(Id genericId) {
        Set<String> validSObjects = new Set<String>();
        validSObjects.add('Opportunity');

        String result;        
        String sObjectType = genericId.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName();

        if (sObjectType == 'Opportunity') {
            result = generateFromOpportunity(genericId);
        } else {
            result = 'Error: Generate called for unsupported SObject Type ' + sObjectType + '\r\n\r\nValid SObject Types are:\r\n';
            for (String soType: validSObjects)
                result += soType + '\r\n';
        }

        return result;
    }

    private static String generateFromOpportunity(Id opId) {

        system.debug('***************************** generateFromOpportunity(Id opId) *********************************');
        system.debug('opId : ' + opId);

        String result;

        List<Opportunity> validateList = new List<Opportunity>([SELECT Id FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = :opId AND Customer_Number__c != null AND Delivery_Customer_State_Province_updated__c != null AND Delivery_Customer_City__c != null AND Delivery_Customer_Name__c != null AND Delivery_Customer_Post_Code__c != null AND Delivery_Customer_State__c != null]);

        if(validateList.isEmpty()) {

            result = 'Error: Required fields missing.\r\n\r\nCustomer Number, Customer Name, Delivery Customer Address 3, Delivery Customer City, Delivery Customer Post Code and Delivery Customer State/Province are required for Output Order.';

        } else {

            date todaysDate = date.today();
            List<Order_Output__c> ooDelete = new List<Order_Output__c>([SELECT Id FROM Order_Output__c WHERE Opportunity__c = :opId AND Order_Date__c = :todaysDate]);
            if (!ooDelete.isEmpty())
                delete ooDelete;

            List<Order_Output__c> ooList = new List<Order_Output__c>();

            List<Opportunity> oList = new List<Opportunity>([SELECT Id, Order_Output__c, (SELECT Id, Order_Output__c, PricebookEntry.Product2.Name, Quantity, LastModifiedDate FROM OpportunityLineItems WHERE Quantity > 0) FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = :opId]);

            system.debug('oList : ' + oList);     

            if(!oList.isEmpty()) {

                //get snapshot qtys
                List<AggregateResult> aList = new List<AggregateResult>([SELECT OLI__c, SUM(Qty__c) FROM Order_Output__c WHERE Opportunity__c = :opId GROUP BY OLI__c]);
                Map<Id, Integer> oliMap = new Map<Id, Integer>();
                for(AggregateResult a : aList) {
                    oliMap.put(String.valueOf(a.get('OLI__c')), Integer.valueOf(a.get('expr0')));
                }

                Opportunity o = oList[0];
                system.debug('o.OpportunityLineItems : ' + o.OpportunityLineItems);

                if(!o.OpportunityLineItems.isEmpty()) {

                    Order_Output__c ooh = new Order_Output__c();
                    ooh.Opportunity__c = o.Id;
                    ooh.Output__c = o.Order_Output__c;
                    ooh.Order__c = 1;
                    ooh.Order_Date__c = System.Today();

                    system.debug('Adding ooh to ooList(line 148)');
                    ooList.add(ooh);

                    Order_Output__c oo;

                    for(OpportunityLineItem oli : o.OpportunityLineItems) {

                        system.debug('oli : '+ oli);

                        system.debug('oli.LastModifiedDate: ' + oli.LastModifiedDate);
                        //system.debug('maxOutputOrderDate: ' + maxOutputOrderDate);

                        //if (oli.LastModifiedDate > maxOutputOrderDate || maxOutputOrderDate == null) {

                            Integer Qty = Integer.valueOf(oli.Quantity);

                            if(oliMap.get(oli.Id) != null){
                                system.debug('oliMap.get(oli.Id) == null');
                                Qty = Qty - oliMap.get(oli.Id);
                            }

                            if(Qty > 0) {

                                system.debug('Quantity is greater than zero');

                                oo = new Order_Output__c();

                                oo.Opportunity__c = o.Id;
                                oo.Output__c = oli.Order_Output__c.replaceAll('\\{QTY}', String.valueOf(Qty)+'.0000');
                                oo.Order_Date__c = System.Today();
                                oo.Product_Name__c = oli.PricebookEntry.Product2.Name;
                                oo.Qty__c = Qty;
                                oo.OLI__c = oli.Id;

                                system.debug('Adding oo to ooList (line 174)');
                                ooList.add(oo);

                            }

                        //}

                    }

                }

            }

            insert ooList;

            result = ooList.Size() + ' Order Lines Outputted';

        }

        return result;

    }


}
```

How can I convert this across?

The button is only used within the Opportunity object to create an EDI for products that have been added.

As an example, I have worked through the following: https://lightning.accorto.com/support/discussions/topics/1000081937

And have been able to get it working to an extent but the code used creates a pop-up page that doesnt format correctly. Within the page the buttons do work so I got half way there.

I have also tried working through the following: 
https://andyinthecloud.com/2013/07/16/how-to-call-apex-code-from-a-custom-button/

Comment: where is your button used currently?  where is it that you will be using it that you want to have a lightning component do the same functionality?  there is no magical solution to converting existing buttons to work in lightning.  First things firts, you want to learn either by reading the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/intro_framework.htm) or/and doing [Trailheads](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules). you might want to post your attempted approaches as well and specify the issues you are encoutnering

Comment: The button is only used within the Opportunity object to create an EDI for products that have been added. 

As an example, I have worked through the following:
http://lightning.accorto.com/support/discussions/topics/1000081937

And have been able to get it working to an extent but the code used creates a pop-up page that doesnt format correctly. Within the page the buttons do work so I got half way there.

I have also tried working through the following:
https://andyinthecloud.com/2013/07/16/how-to-call-apex-code-from-a-custom-button/

Comment: mind updating your post with the above?

Comment: I have updated my original

Answer (score 1):

> Winter'17 Has introduced Great feature to use a Lightning Component from an Action 
>   More Details can be found here [Lightning Alternatives to JavaScript Buttons](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/lex_javascript_button_migration)

You need to pass parameters which you are passing using custom JavaScript button using lightning component attributes. 
[Component Attributes](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_attributes.htm)

Your Apex Class `orderOutput` has Method `generate` which accepts `Id genericId` which is OpportunityId as I can understand from your code

```
var result = sforce.apex.execute("orderOutput","generate", {genericId:"{!Opportunity.Id}"});
```

I am giving you example to pass OpportunityId from Lightning component as per your need you can pass multiple parameters by defining attributes inside Lightning component.

You can use  [force:hasRecordId](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_interfaces_force_hasrecordid.htm) to pass OpportunityId to your Apex Controller.
Other Interfaces you can implement are:

```
implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction"
```

`force:lightningQuickAction`, has been added to the platform to indicate
 that your component supports Actions

> Add the force:hasRecordId interface to a Lightning component to enable
>   the component to be assigned the ID of the current record. The current
>   record ID is useful if the component is used on a Lightning record
>   page, as an object-specific custom action or action override in
>   Lightning Experience or the Salesforce app, and so on. This interface
>   has no effect except when used within Lightning Experience, Salesforce
>   app, and template-based communities.

Create Lightning Component.

```
<aura:component controller="YourApexController" implements="force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >
    <!-- Define Attribute For Current recordId -->
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" />
    <!-- Define Attribute To Open Pop-up --> 
    <aura:attribute name="yesNoOptions" type="boolean" default="false"/>

    <!--- Display Pop-Up For Yes/No Option To Perform Your Action. --> 
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.yesNoOptions}">
      <div role="alertdialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="prompt-heading-id" aria-describedby="prompt-message-wrapper" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open slds-modal--prompt">
         <div class="slds-modal__container">
            <div class="slds-modal__header slds-theme--success slds-theme--alert-texture">
               <h2 class="slds-text-heading--medium" id="prompt-heading-id">Heading As per Your Choice</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around--medium">
               <div>
                  <p>Header For Your Model Pop-up Box</p>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-modal__footer slds-theme--default">
               <!-- If User Clicks Yes Then Call Controller Action.-->
               <button class="slds-button slds-button--brand" onclick="{!c. functionaName}">Yes</button>
                <!-- If User Clicks No Then Close Pop-up.-->
               <button class="slds-button slds-button--brand" onclick="{!c.closeMessage}">No</button>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop--open"></div>
    </aura:if>
    <!-- Add Component Description -->
        <div class="slds-m-around--medium" >
           <div class="slds-container--medium">
            <div class="slds-form--stacked">
              <div class="slds-form-element">                
                Add Description here which will explain What this component is About <br/>
              </div>
              <div class="slds-form-element">                
                  <!---Button Which Will Open Pop-up--> 
                  <button class="slds-button slds-button--brand" style="margin-
                          left: 39%;" onclick="{!c.openDialog}">Your Button Name</button>

              </div>
              <br/>              
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>   
</aura:component>
```

Your Lightning Component Controller , you can do following to get OpportunityId

```
     //This is method of your Component controller
     functionaName : function(component, event, helper) {
         //get Opportunity Record Id
         var getOpportunityId = component.get("v.recordId");

         helper.yourHelperFunctionName(component,getOpportunityId );

     },

     //When User Clicks on Your Button inside Componet, this will open 
      //Dailog with Yes/No Option, you can configure buttons and name of buttons as per your choice.
     openDialog: function(component, event, helper) {
         component.set("v.yesNoOptions", true);        
     },

     //Hide Dailog Box by setting attribute to false 
     closeMessage: function(component, event, helper) {       
        component.set("v.yesNoOptions", false);        
     },
```

Send parameter to your Apex Controller, You can pass multiple parameters as per your need, I am just giving you one example, for that you need to define attributes with datatypes in your Lightning Component.

> ```
> yourHelperFunctionName: function(component,getOpportunityId ) {
>         //Call Your Apex Controller Method.
>         var action = component.get("c.yourApexControllermethod");
>         // set Opportunity RecordId to yourApexController method, parameter name should be exact match as that of apex method parameter name.   
>         action.setParams({
>             'genericId': getOpportunityId 
>         });
>
>         action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
>             var state = response.getState();
>                 if (state === "SUCCESS") {
>                     //Do Something
>                 } else {
>                     //Do Something
>                 }
>             }            
>         });
>         $A.enqueueAction(action);
>
>
>     },
> ```

Now in Your Apex Controller, you need to add  @AuraEnabled annotation to your Apex Method.
[AuraEnabled Annotation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_AuraEnabled.htm)

> ```
>  public class YourApexClass {
>      @AuraEnabled
>     public static String yourApexControllermethod (Id genericId) {
>          //Do Something , you have your OpportunityId here
>            //As parameter list goes up, you need to add parameters here "," seperated
>     }
> }
> ```

1. You can add Lightning component on Opportunity Record page using Lightning App builder.
2. Another Option is You can create New Action and attach Lightning Component it.